# How to tell which device in /dev a kernel module added?

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

I have just compiled the QLogic `qla2xxx` FC driver on a CentOS6.4 host, and done

```
echo 'alias scsi_hostadapter qla2xxx' >> /etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf

cd /boot
cp initramfs-$(uname -r).img initramfs-$(uname -r).img.bak
mkinitrd -f initramfs-$(uname -r).img `uname -r`
reboot
```

When doing `lshw` it is shown as

```
description: Fibre Channel
product: QLogic Corp.
vendor: QLogic Corp.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
version: 02
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress vpd msix bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=qla2xxx latency=0
resources: irq:24 memory:dcefa000-dcefbfff(prefetchable) memory:dcefc000-dcefffff(prefetchable) memory:dcf00000-dcffffff(prefetchable) memory:dffc0000-dfffffff(prefetchable)
```

**Question**

How can I figure out which device the driver created in `dev`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There won't be a device entry until actual disks are connected. After that, you can see those with `lsscsi`, which you might need to install first.

Comment: In my case a NetApp is connected at the other end of the FC cable. Can I somehow force(?) the device to be created, so I can enter the device name into a config file?